# Get access of active socket

Tags: java, sockets, scala, operating-system

I'd like to somehow get control over active sockets on my computer with java/scala. For example, if a program has stablished a tcp connection, i want to be able to retrieve and listen/write onto this socket.

So, the first question is: is that possible?
And the second: how?

Comment: Are you talking about reading sockets from other programs or sockets that your own Java application has opened?

Comment: Exactly, from other programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a custom Socket factory.  This is fairly complicated and I don't suggest you do this unless you are trying a to hack a program you have no control over (again a very bad idea)

Instead I suggest you monitor your own usage.  When you read/write from a Socket you also keep any information you need. i.e Its your program so change it to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a java wrapper of lipcap http://jnetpcap.com/ that let me do the sort of things i was after. From the web:
jNetPcap is an open-source java library. It contains:

> A Java wrapper for nearly all libpcap library native calls
>   Decodes captured packets in real-time
>   Provides a large library of network protocols (core protocols)
>   Users can easily add their own protocol definitions using java SDK
>   jNetPcap uses a mixture of native and java implementation for optimum packet decoding performance